# Writing variable content to file in ansible

Tags: file, ansible, var

I trying to write variable content to file in ansible as follow what I not have lucky.

tasks:

```
- name: Collect some information about rootvg space.
  raw: "df -h |grep /$ |awk -F / '{print $4}' |awk '{print $1}' |cut -d - -f1 |/usr/bin/xargs sudo /usr/sbin/vgs --noheading"
  register: res

- name: Send to local file
  local_action: copy content="{{ res }}" dest="/tmp/rootvg_space.log"
```

Am I trying the correct way to do that?

Comment: What happens when you run that? What does the log file contain in this case?

Comment: Hi @nwinkler, I got the error you can see as follow :                                 TASK [Send to local file] ************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
fatal: [itibmchefworkstation01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: Collect some information about rootvg space
  shell: "df -h |grep /$ |awk -F / '{print $4}' |awk '{print $1}' |cut -d - -f1 |/usr/bin/xargs sudo /usr/sbin/vgs --noheading"
  register: res

- name: Send to local file
  local_action: copy content="{{ res.stdout }}" dest="/tmp/rootvg_space.log"
```

Comment: Hi @JGK, I got the same error look at this.... TASK [Send to local file] ************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
fatal: [itibmchefworkstation01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

Comment: Try `local_action: copy content="{{ res.stdout }}" dest="~/rootvg_space.log"` just for debugging. The error messages states **No such file or directory** so there might be no `/tmp` or you don't have rights? Strange.

Comment: Yes, it's weird, I tried as you asked **dest="~/rootvg_space.log"** but I have the same error. I wondering if it same code bug. Is there another way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I found out the issue, I changed sh exec pointing to /home/ibmunx/ansible-py, and missed to create that link in ansible mngmnt node, so, when it tried to exec on localhost didn't exist: I figured out this trying -vvv <localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /home/ibmunx/ansible-py -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0' - Thank your help.